# oclint: oclint-json-compilation-database returns "Skipping [Path] Command line not found."

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild, code-metrics, oclint

After (seemingly) successfully generating compile_commands.json with oclint-xcodebuild, oclint-json-compilation-database fails to correctly create a pmd-style report.

The command looks like this:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -e Pods -v -- -report-type=pmd -o=oclint.xml -debug
```

It returns:

```
Skipping [Path to Directory with compile_commands.json]. Command line not found.
```

I'm using oclint 0.7.

Answer (score 2):

Use latest dev 0.8 or 0.9

for me it corrected the bug.

Seen in [Sonar Plugin for Objective C](https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c), Prerequisites, point 4.

Comment: I can't check this right now but will come back and marked as solved if this will have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your command needs to be changed. No "=" required. It should look like this:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -e Pods -v -- -report-type pmd -o oclint.xml -debug
```